# How to upload multiple files using react bootstrap Form.File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, api

```
 onFileChange = event => {
    console.log(event.target.files);
    
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('files', event.target.files[0]);
      try {
        axios({
          method: "post",
          url: "https://smk-cms-strapi.herokuapp.com/upload",
          header: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          data: formData
        }).then(({ data }) => {
          console.log("Succesfully uploaded: ", JSON.stringify(data));

          this.handleInputChange({
            target: {
              name: 'file',
              value: data,
            },
          });
        });
      } catch (error) {
        this.setState({ error });
      }
  };


<FormR.File name="file" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
```

this is my code

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the files and append them to the  **formData**

```
 let files = event.target.files;
 let formData = new FormData();
 for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append("file", files[i]);
 }
```